# Porting PHP iterative function which uses "static" to Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for the best way to implement a method originally from a PHP class in Ruby. The method uses PHP's "static" keyword to create a counter which can remember it's value from the last time the function was called.

```
function fetchRule()
{
    static $index = 0;
    $ret = null;
    if(isset($this->rules[$index]))
    {
        $ret = $this->rules[$index];
    }
    $index = $ret == null ? 0 : $index++;
    return $ret;
}
```

As you can see rules is an array member of the object. Every time the function is called it gets the next rule and then returns null at the end. I need to port this to ruby. There are probably a dozen ways to do it but I'm hoping to keep it simple.

Answer (score 0):

Here the method in pure Ruby.

```
def fetch_rule
  @rule_index ||= 0   # An instance variable of the object which will be set only if @rule_index is nil
  ret = @rules[@rule_index]   # A local variable

  # Increases the index or resets it to 0 if `ret` is nil.
  @rule_index = (ret.nil? ? 0 : @rule_index++)

  ret    # Returns the value implicitly. WARNING! Returns nil if the method reaches the end of the Array!
end
```

I think you have a small bug in your code above because you reset `$index` on every call to `0`.

You should also check out [TryRuby](http://tryruby.org/). It's a cool tutorial to start with Ruby.

Comment: In order to understand how $index is used, you have to understand how "static" variables work in PHP. Ruby doesn't have these but that's actually not a bug. $index is set once and remembers the value it had the last time the call was made. If it has one it doesn't reset it. Thus it acts as a counter
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php